# my springcloud gateway hava a bug java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Tags: java, spring-boot, indexoutofboundsexception, spring-cloud-gateway

spring cloud version : Greenwich.SR3
gateway version : 2.1.3.RELEASE

this is a Weird bug ,my project start ok and test success, it is run some day , one day it is have this bug .

I also check my cpu,memory,disk. only use 70%, and I test on my local, can not find this bug.

```java
2022-03-06 13:01:11.396 [reactor-http-epoll-5] ERROR o.s.b.a.w.r.error.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler.error:122 - [956eb507] 500 Server Error for HTTP POST "/recharge/mobile/order"
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:659)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:435)
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.combinePredicates(RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.java:221)
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.convertToRoute(RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.java:143)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:100)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drainLoop(FluxFlatMap.java:695)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drain(FluxFlatMap.java:571)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onSubscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:955)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:139)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:63)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:7923)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:420)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:243)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:201)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:366)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:139)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:63)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.subscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:97)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap.subscribe(FluxMap.java:62)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap.subscribe(FluxMap.java:62)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:7923)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:420)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:243)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:201)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:366)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:139)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:63)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.subscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:97)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollectList.subscribe(MonoCollectList.java:40)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoMapFuseable.subscribe(MonoMapFuseable.java:59)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlattenIterable.subscribe(MonoFlattenIterable.java:101)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMaterialize.subscribe(FluxMaterialize.java:40)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollectList.subscribe(MonoCollectList.java:40)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekFuseable.subscribe(MonoPeekFuseable.java:74)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlattenIterable.subscribe(MonoFlattenIterable.java:101)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDematerialize.subscribe(FluxDematerialize.java:39)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefer.subscribe(FluxDefer.java:54)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:7923)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribeWith(Flux.java:8087)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:7916)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:7880)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:7798)
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter.lambda$onApplicationEvent$0(WeightCalculatorWebFilter.java:133)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectProvider.ifAvailable(ObjectProvider.java:93)
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter.onApplicationEvent(WeightCalculatorWebFilter.java:133)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:402)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:359)
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.actuate.AbstractGatewayControllerEndpoint.refresh(AbstractGatewayControllerEndpoint.java:85)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    ...
```

this is my config

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway: 
      routes:
         - id: recharge-mobile
           uri: lb://recharge-mobile
           predicates:
             - Path=/recharge/mobile/**
           filters:
             - StripPrefix=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same bug, spring cloud version : Greenwich.SR3 gateway version : 2.2.1.RELEASE, I can not find this bug

Comment: Please don't post "me too" as an answer. The answer function is to be used for real solutions only.

Answer (score 0):

I just find a solution, update spring cloud gateway version to 2.2.1.RELEASE. I am not sure it can work, but you can try it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug of spring cloud gateway, plslook this: https://tanzu.vmware.com/security/cve-2022-22947

You can close the endpoint in config file,like this:

management:

endpoint:

```
gateway:

  enabled: false
```

Comment: You can close the endpoint in config file,like this:

 management:
  endpoint:
    gateway:
      enabled: false